# Фильтрация ListView из EditText

Tags: android, listview, фильтрация, android-edittext

Не могу разобраться с фильтрацией в ListView. Фильтрация происходит правильно (находит нужное количество), но выводит не те, которые нужно (например не 1, 3 и 5), а первые из списка(1-3).

**MainActivity:**

```
private EditText etSearch; // Строка для поиска

private List<Passenger> list; // лист объектов
private List<Passenger> allPassenger; // буферный лист для всех объектов

private ListView lv; //ListView
private ArrayAdapter<Passenger> adapter; // адаптер

...

etSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSearch);


// инициализация массивов элементов
list = new ArrayList<>();
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPassengers);
adapter = new PassengerAdapter(this);

...
// заполнение массивов объектами
list.add(new Passenger(id, surname, numberCar, typeCar, positionTypeCar, terminal, positionTerminals, date));
allPassenger = new ArrayList<>(list);

 // вывод колличества объектов
 tvAll.setText(String.valueOf(adapter.getCount()));
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
 // поиск через EditText
 etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

**Класс Passenger:**

```
public class Passenger {
    public final int id;
    public final String surname;
    public final String numberCar;
    public final String typeCar;
    public final int positionTypeCar;
    public final String terminal;
    public final int positionTerminal;
    public final String date;

    public Passenger(int id, String surname, String numberCar, String typeCar, int positionTypeCar, String terminal, int positionTerminal, String date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.numberCar = numberCar;
        this.typeCar = typeCar;
        this.positionTypeCar = positionTypeCar;
        this.terminal = terminal;
        this.positionTerminal = positionTerminal;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

**Адаптер и фильтр:**

```
private class PassengerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Passenger> implements Filterable {
    public PassengerAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, list);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount (){
      return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Passenger passenger = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.surname))
                .setText(passenger.surname);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberCar))
                .setText(passenger.numberCar);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.typeCar))
                .setText(passenger.typeCar);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date))
                .setText(passenger.date);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.terminal))
                .setText(passenger.terminal);
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    result.values = allPassenger;
                    result.count = allPassenger.size();
                }
                else{
                    ArrayList<Passenger> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(Passenger p: allPassenger){
                        if(p.surname.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                            filteredList.add(p); //Где то здесь ошибка
                    }
                    result.values = filteredList;
                    result.count = filteredList.size();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                list = (ArrayList<Passenger>) results.values;
                tvAll.setText(String.valueOf(results.count));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Нашла ошибку! Как всегда из-за не внимательности, забыла добавить метод `getItem()` в адаптер. Вот исправленный адаптер:

```
    private class PassengerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Passenger> implements Filterable {
    public PassengerAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, list);
    }

    @Override
    public Passenger getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount (){
      return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        Passenger passenger = getItem(position);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.surname))
                .setText(passenger.surname);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberCar))
                .setText(passenger.numberCar);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.typeCar))
                .setText(passenger.typeCar);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date))
                .setText(passenger.date);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.terminal))
                .setText(passenger.terminal);
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    result.values = allPassenger;
                    result.count = allPassenger.size();
                }
                else{
                    ArrayList<Passenger> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(Passenger p: allPassenger){
                        if(p.surname.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                            filteredList.add(p);
                    }
                    result.values = filteredList;
                    result.count = filteredList.size();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                list = (ArrayList<Passenger>) results.values;
                tvAll.setText(String.valueOf(results.count));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```